# Python Libraries In Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

I recently did a factory reset on my pc, I installed python and visual studio code, installed some libraries and when I tried to use them visual studio code didn't found those libraries and also, sometimes visual studio code notifies me that I don't have installed pylint but when I click on install it says that there is no Pip installer in the selected environment. I added the python folder and the scripts folder to path and I've searched for the same error I have everywhere and nothing seemed to work. I don't know what to do.

Comment: What does the VSCode terminal display when you use the commands "python --version" and "pip --version"? Usually, python comes with pip, if there is no pip, you need to install it. When pip is available, VSCode can use the pip command to install the required modules. In addition, what is the VSCode environment you are currently using, and could you provide us with the steps for your operation.

Comment: @JillCheng When I use python --version or pip --version it displays the version of python and pip like it works normally. But when I try to use any library that I have installed or when I click on install pylint when visual studio says so it displays and error as it could not find pip or the libraries I have installed. I've never worked with environments in visual studio code, before doing the factory reset it worked fine with just installing the libraries that I wanted and then vs code would recognize them automatically.

Comment: Have you tried to install the module "Pylint" manually in the VSCode terminal? (pip install pylint)  When you use "pip list", is there "pylint" in the list? Could you provide us with screenshots of relevant information and error messages?

Comment: @JillCheng Yeah so thanks to what you said before I know now that the error is in the python extension of visual studio code, here there are some screenshots of what is happening, [imgur](https://imgur.com/a/ddTkfgJ) as you can see, pylint is installed with a bunch of other libraries but when I execute any file it can not find those libraries or if pip is installed.

Comment: Thank you for providing us with information. What [VSCode environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) are you currently using? From the screenshot, these modules installed by pip are not in the current python interpreter environment, or in other words, the current environment is not an environment containing these modules. Please try to use the shortcut key "Ctrl+Shift+`" to open a new VScode terminal, it will automatically enter the current environment.

Comment: In addition, It is recommended that you could try other VSCode terminals.(Ctrl+Shift+` , "Terminal: Select Default Shell" , "Command Prompt")

Comment: @JillCheng So if I create a new file and save it in for example the downloads folder it works normally but the issue comes when I execute the files that are in my workspace, when I add my projects to the workspace python thinks that the modules and configuration are also on my projects folder wich is not true. I remember before the factory reset, having all my projects in my workspace and working correctly but now python is searching for the libraries and configuration in there. Is that what the environment is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the problem was not related mainly to visual studio code, I had one program installed called inkscape that installs python in another path, visual studio code detected that path before the path of where I had python installed. The solution was to uninstall inkscape if someone has a similar problem, I guess I could tell inkscape to not install python or tell visual studio code to not search on another paths but when I tried to do so it didn't work so the easiest solution was uninstalling Inkscape. I also appreciate the help of @JillCheng to isolate the source of the error.